# Matplotlib Animation - trouble with the speed of the saved file

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, save

I am trying to make animations using `Python-Matplotlib`.

I am using this tutorial:

http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/

The animation in the first example works fine when I just execute
the Python script, however in order to be able to save it (`anim.save command`),
I had to add '`writer=animation.FFMpegFileWriter()`' as an argument. Now however
the saved file plays *much* slower than the original file. In fact the video
is always 40 seconds long, no matter to what value I set '`interval`' in the
`FuncAnimation` object.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similar problem saving with FFMpeg.

A solution that worked for me was to modify

```
writer=animation.FFMpegFileWriter()
```

to read

```
writer=animation.FFMpegFileWriter(fps=n)
```

where n is your desired output frames per second.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the desired frames per second as an argument:

```
anim.save('filename.mp4', fps=120, writer=animation.FFMpegFileWriter())
```